# Can't select blog month within archive category

Tags: permalinks, archives

I'm using Wordpress 4.1.1. I have come across a problem with my website archives. If I set the permalinks to default I can click on a category and then click on the date on the sidebar within this category and it displays results for that month. This is the permalink:

> ?cat=16&m=201503

However if I change the permalinks to Post Name I get this structure:

> category/category-1/?m=201503

but I don't arrive at the page. It just times out. I don't even get re-direct to a 404 page. I get page with this message:

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>       Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Have I set up my permalink structure incorrectly? Or is this some other issue?

Answer (score 0):

### A canonical redirect:

The GET parameter `m` can trigger a *canonical redirect* when permalinks are used.

The canonical redirects are activated with the following hook:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

where [`redirect_canonical()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/canonical.php#L39) is a rather complicated function.

Here's the skeleton of the part that's active within this "monster" callback:

```
// ... cut ...

if ( is_404() ) {

    // ... cut ...

} elseif ( is_object($wp_rewrite) && $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) {

   if( ... ) {

      // ... cut ...

    } elseif ( !empty($_GET['m']) && ( is_year() || is_month() || is_day() ) ) {

        // --> We are here <---  ;-)

    } elseif( ... ) {

    // ... cut ...

}

// ... cut ...
```

where `$_GET['m']` is non-empty.

In your case when `$m` has the `YYYYMM` format, `is_month()` is also true and we get the following redirect:

```
$redirect_url = get_month_link( substr($m, 0, 4), substr($m, 4, 2) );
```

so we should be redirected from:

```
http://example.tld/category/category-1/?m=201503
```

to:

```
 http://example.tld/2015/03
```

A possible workaround would by to use instead:

```
http://example.tld/2015/03/?cat=16
```

to avoid the canonical redirect process.

You should also try this on a vanilla install: default theme and no plugins to avoid your infinite redirect loop problem.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me. What do I do with the http://example.tld/2015/03/?cat=16 ?

Comment: This was just an example you one could filter the posts by both date and category, without the canonical redirection. I don't think your click-combination will  work by default for permalinks. I tried it on the default theme, but didn't succeed with the permalinks off. One would need to handle this with somekind of GET parameters collector for the links. @Gennie

Comment: ps: I meant to write in the above comment: "you one could" as "how one could" ;-)

Comment: Well, I gave up and I've created a new sidebar for category archive pages which does not display the monthly archive widget.